# VTK volume rendering of mammography

Tags: c++, vtk

I am working on vtk volume rendering of mammography. I have a 50 DICOM slices in folder to construct volume. Here I need to give `vtkColorTransferFunction` and `vtkPiecewiseFunction` to set RGB color and scalar opacity.

I am not getting exact values of color and opacity with respect to mammo images (breast images). I need values for color and opacity with respect to breast x-ray images.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper *volumeGPUmapper = 
vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper::New();

volumeGPUmapper->SetInputConnection(clip->GetOutputPort());

// RGB and alpha funcions
double skinOnBlueMap[28][5] =
{
      {0,     0.987853825092316, 1.0,               1.0,               0.9},
      {10000, 0.987853825092316, 1.0,               1.0,               0.9},
      {20000, 0.987853825092316, 1.0,               1.0,               1.0},
      {30000, 0.987853825092316, 1.0,               1.0,               1.0},
      {40000, 0.0,               0.0,               0.0,               1.0},
      {50000, 1.0,               0.0,               0.0,               1.0},
      {60000, 1.0,               0.999206542968750, 0.0,               1.0},
      {70000, 1.0,               1.0,               1.0,               1.0}
};

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> alphaChannelFunc = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> colorFunc = vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(skinOnBlueMap)/(5*sizeof(double)); i++)
{
    colorFunc->AddRGBPoint(skinOnBlueMap[i][0], skinOnBlueMap[i][1], skinOnBlueMap[i][2], skinOnBlueMap[i][3]);

    alphaChannelFunc->AddPoint(skinOnBlueMap[i][0], skinOnBlueMap[i][4]);
}

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty>::New();

volumeProperty->SetColor(colorFunc);
volumeProperty->SetInterpolationTypeToLinear();
volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(alphaChannelFunc);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume> VTKvolume = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolume>::New();

VTKvolume->SetMapper(volumeGPUmapper);

VTKvolume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can post the current output and, if possible, the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Those scalar values seem strange to me. It could be the reason your results don't look correct. But to be sure we need the image stack and rendered result.

The scalar values are not even inside the range of the unsigned short type, that is generally used for the voxels.